# What does the term "pending dispatch" means?

Tags: c#, wcf, nettcpbinding

According to MSDN , the "MaxConnections" parameter means:

> The NetTcpBinding.MaxConnections
>   property controls the maximum number
>   of connections to be pooled for
>   subsequent reuse on the client and the
>   maximum number of connections allowed
>   to be ***pending dispatch*** on the server.

what does the term "Pending Dispatch" mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In WCF, "dispatch" is the process of deciding which method to call given an incoming SOAP message. A "pending dispatch" means that the server hasn't finished deciding which message is the right one to send. The value of `MaxConnections` determines how many of these decisions the server can be making simultaneously, at maximum.